# How to add input box dynamically with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to append n number of input box fields in html form on a button click.

```
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
   <div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-11 classTextbox" id="TextBoxDiv1">
     <input type="text" id='AB1' name="name[]" placeholder="" >
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
    <a id="addFieldBtn"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
     </a>
</div>
```

Here is the screenshot of my above code :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR2Es.png

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following jquery on button click (with id 'addFieldBtn') :

```
        $("#addFieldBtn").click(function () {
               jQuery('#TextBoxesGroup .classTextbox').addClass('marginBottom10');
               var counter = 2;
               var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter).attr("class", 'marginBottom10 col-sm-11 col-xs-11');

               newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="text" name="name[]' + counter +
               '" id="AB' + counter + '" Placeholder="" >');

               newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
               counter++;
           });
```

And this css for adding space after every input field:

```
<style>
.marginBottom10{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
</style>
```

Here is my output now : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E34mf.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `append()`. to appent the html contents.

Please try the below sample code

```js
var counter=2;
$('#addFieldBtn').click(function(){
$('#TextBoxesGroup').append('<div class="col-md-11 classTextbox" id="TextBoxDiv1" style="  margin-bottom:10px;"> <input type="text" id="AB'+counter+'" name="name[]" placeholder="" > </div>');
counter++
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id='TextBoxesGroup' class="row">
   <div class="col-md-11 classTextbox" id="TextBoxDiv1">
     <input type="text" id='AB1' name="name[]" placeholder="" >
   </div>

<div class="col-md-1">
    <a id="addFieldBtn"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
     </a>
</div>
</div>
```

**Update**

If you want to add the textbox **before the first child**.

```
$('#TextBoxesGroup').prepend(".....");
```

If you want to add the textbox  **after the first child**.

```
$('#TextBoxesGroup').append(".....");
```